# I'm trying to get and print random pokemon using Api, but it gives me the error 404

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

This is API site link: https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon

This is API example: [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{id](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/%7Bid) or name}/

this is store.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'

let serverHost = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2'

export const pokeStore = defineStore("pokemons", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      pokemons: []
    };
  },
  actions: {
    async getOnePokemon(id) {
      try {
        let response = await axios.get(`${serverHost}/pokemon/${id}`)
        if(response.data){
          response.data.name = response.data.name.replace('-', " ");
        let pokemon = {
          id: response.data.id,
          name: response.data.name,
          image: response.data.sprites.front_default
        }
        if(!pokemon.image){
          pokemon.image = response.data.sprites.front_shiny
        }
        return pokemon
      }
      } catch (error) {
        this.getOnePokemon(Math.floor(Math.random() * 151) + 1)
      }
    },
    
  }
});
```

this is home where im trying to print random pokemon:

````
```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { pokeStore } from '../store/store'
const PokemonStore = pokeStore();

let allpokemonsIds = ref<any>()


 async function GetPokemons() {
  try {
    let response = await PokemonStore.getOnePokemon();
    allpokemonsIds.value = response;
    console.log(allpokemonsIds.value)

  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

GetPokemons()

</script>
````

I want to get random pokemon from the first 151 pokemon and print it using the console log in the Home component

Comment: Can. you print out the URL you are generating before making the call. What does it show?

Comment: What is `console.log('${serverHost}/pokemon/${id}')`?

Comment: I dont understand what do you want me to do

Comment: You said it gives you a 404. Well you've shown the code that is generating the URL. But you haven't actually shown the URL that you are trying to access. I was just asking to see what the actual generated URL is. Do you know it's a valid URL? What if the URL is not what you expect? Like it might be... `/pokemon/20.0000`? That would make a 404.

Comment: this is what I get in console log
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/undefined   xhr.js:247
and 
undefined  Home.vue:16

Comment: Well there's your problem.

Comment: I dont get it sorry Im new to proggraming

Comment: No worries. So, your maths to calculate the random number is not working. It's returning an `undefined` value. Which is what you're seeing in the url and then why you're seeing the 404. I'll try to find why.

Comment: Oh... actually... this line... `let response = await PokemonStore.getOnePokemon();` is running your function without passing in the `id` and so that's why it's undefined. Update it to... `let response = await PokemonStore.getOnePokemon(1);` and you will see it work but it won't be random.

Comment: should I zip the code and send it if it will help you?

Comment: yes I get the bulbasaur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this...

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'

let serverHost = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2'

export const pokeStore = defineStore("pokemons", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      pokemons: []
    };
  },
  actions: {
    async getOnePokemon() {
      try {
        let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 151) + 1; // <- I have changed this...
        let response = await axios.get(`${serverHost}/pokemon/${id}`)
        if(response.data){
          response.data.name = response.data.name.replace('-', " ");
          let pokemon = {
            id: response.data.id,
            name: response.data.name,
            image: response.data.sprites.front_default
          }
          if(!pokemon.image){
            pokemon.image = response.data.sprites.front_shiny
          }
          return pokemon
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
    
  }
});
```

You had some code in the `catch` that was trying to do the random id nbut that's not where that should go.

I've updated to generate the random id in the function instead of passing the id in.

Comment: No worries. Make sure to up vote and accept any answers that are correct. It helps give back to the community in StackOverflow. :D

Comment: just click on the check mark?

Comment: and I also have another problem to solve if you are for it, it is related to login and cookies. I think that all the code is done, it just needs to be rewritten maybe some line, I don't know what the problem is